C# documentation link to method but show only method name without parameters
I want to show link with only method name as text. Is there a way to set link to method and change text? This is all I know: <see cref="ScrapePatentsByWindows"/> and it looks like this:

How can I remove class name and method parameters so it only says ScrapePatentsByWindows, like this (edited image):

